# 404 error on http - let's encrypt certbot , everything fine with https

Tags: nginx, ssl, http-status-code-404, lets-encrypt

I'm using certbot to generate a let's encrypt certificate, everything work fine except the http version is not redirected to the https.

Here is my .conf in sites-available :

```
    # the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    server_name deussearch.fr www.deussearch.fr;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/deussearch.fr.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_Host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.deussearch.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.deussearch.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.deussearch.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name deussearch.fr www.deussearch.fr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I really can't find what's wrong here, like I followed tutorial and everything worked fine , anyone know ? I'm using Nginx on ubuntu if it can help !

Answer (score 0):

I have check your website it's OK. Every I try access http://deussearch.fr/ always redirect to https://www.deussearch.fr/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Ew4.png

You can also check in https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=deussearch.fr

Comment: I can second this, http:// is redirecting for me as well. Sometimes clearing the browser cache can resolve weird 301 issues if an old 301 was replaced by a new one.